# What Would the Uses of Domesticated Bunyips be?

Tags: fauna, civilization, domestication, prehistoric-times

In my book series, one of the main cultures has domesticated *Diprotodon Optatum* (called "Bunyips" in-universe). For those of you who don't know, here's what they look like (they're the herd of giant wombats in the background):

[image]

In size, these behemoths are about 9.8 feet long, 6.6 feet tall at the shoulder, and weigh about 6,150 lbs. To a civilization living in what would best be described as a much more mountainous version of Pleistocene Australia, what would these creatures best be used for if they were domesticated?

Comment: One imagines beasts-of-burden and meat. I suspect they are rubbish at catching mice or bookkeeping, and they look like they eat a bit more than a dog for keeping watch or shepherding.

Comment: If they are domesticated you have to feed them.  Feeding large creatures like this is not very efficient unless you get some really significant return for it.    They do not look suited to mountainous terrain (either wild or domesticated), so it sounds dubious to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would fall into the same category as Elephants, Oxen, and Water Buffalo, most likely.

It really depends on their temperament.  Since we don't have any alive today, you could probably make that part up and that will flow into what they would be used for.

If they are slow and thoughtful critters, you could simply use them for two things:  Pulling (or carrying) heavy stuff, pulling plows, and for fertilizer.  A critter that size could really enrich the loam, so to speak.  This latter also kind of depends on the nature of the digestive tract, whether its more like a cow.  If they poop cubes like regular wombats and they are that big, maybe look into the brick making potential.

If they are more aggressive, you could still have them pull large loads like Oxen, but they could also be used as war beasts.  The purpose of a war stallion is as much as for momentum as it is for trampling and such.  If they have claws that are good for digging or climbing that is a bonus.  Their teeth might be a useful weapon in combat, destroying leather armor with ease.

Another note about the teeth.  because they resemble beaver teeth, they might also be good for forest clearing.

Looks like a neat idea

Comment: If they were to make poop cube architecture, how would they get rid of the smell?

Comment: @The Weasel Sagas - Try searching for *building with dung* - It's a thing. Here's an article https://www.globalcitizen.org/en/content/who-uses-sht-to-build-a-house/